# Having issue with file appended with date in JIL script

Tags: shell, autosys, jil

I have a file watcher job, which is expecting to receive daily file with date appended.

```
 insert_job: FILE_WATCHER   job_type: FW 
 box_name: abc_BOX
 machine: abc.com
 owner: dev
 permission: mx,me
 date_conditions: 0
 job_terminator: 1
 alarm_if_fail: 0
 alarm_if_terminated: 0
 watch_file: "/somelocation/FILE_`date +%Y%m%d`.csv"
```

But this date formatter is failing. Can anyone please suggest any better option.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a simple fix for the solution:

```
watch_file: "/somelocation/FILE_*.csv"
```

Sometimes answer is simple and we try to think a lot more than that